# RailsCast 197: nested forms Unknown Attribute

Tags: nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two tables:
Quote and Part.  I am using the rails 3.1 ruby 1.9.2.  My code is as follows:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :customer_id, :part_id, :date, :quote_id
has_many    :customers
has_many    :cycles
has_many    :parts, #:dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts 

end


class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :quote

end
```

QuotesController

```
def new
  @quote = Quote.new
  @customers=Customer.find(:all)
  @cycles = Cycle.find(:all)
  1.times {@quote.parts.build}

end
```

_form

```
<% f.fields_for :parts do |builder| %>
<%= render "cycle_fields", :f => builder%>
```

I am getting an unknown attribute: quote_id when I try to render the form.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this migration

```
    rails g migration AddIdToPart quote_id:integer
    rake db:migrate
```